# Different orientation in one HTML file

Tags: html

In one html, can I have multiple page orientation? (e.g. 1st page potrait, 2nd page landscape, 3rd page potrait, 4th page landscape)

Or there's only one page in HTML?

The reason being, I would like to convert one html to one pdf (with different orientation for different pages)

Comment: What method are you using to convert the pages to PDF? This may be relevant.

Comment: I'm using pdfTron framework which uses the paperSize to control the orientation:  [PTConvert convertHTMLStringToPDF:dataString baseURL:nil paperSize:pageSize completion: ^ (NSString * pathToPDF) {...} I'm a able to achieve it using multiple html files (with different orientation) and rendering/converting it individually. However, intermittently it will create a blank page. So i'm considering to concatenate all the html into one html and hopefully can support both orientation

Comment: @TidyDev is there a way to run block codes sequentially and not in parallel?